# Error with shared library recoding malloc

Tags: c, malloc, ld-preload

I'm trying to implement my own version of `malloc` making a shared library but I'm facing a problem.
When I run my `malloc` with `LD_PRELOAD` this message appear:

> Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-load.c: 2325: _dl_map_object: Assertion nsid < _rtld_local._dl_nns failed!

This appear when I launch the command `ls -lRa /home`
My `LD_PRELOAD` path is ok because the command ls works.
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: You need to post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In short, post your code.